# How to change actual size of view with Animations?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want the view's real size to change with the animation. It only changes the content right now. I am changing scale Y from 1.0 to 0.0 and the animation happens but leaves an empty space where the view used to be. Also, I tried View.GONE but that snaps the other views into the empty space when animation ends, but I need the other views to follow the scaling view's size while it shrinks. How to get that working?

I've put this already and it doesn't help!

```
fillAfter="true"
fillEnabled="true"
```

Comment: You can't change it "with the animations," but you can adjust the LayoutParams of the View after the animation has finished. Take a look at the AnimationListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Comment: But its the same as doing View.GONE! I want the other views to follow the shrinking!

Comment: Try with `View.INVISIBLE`

Comment: I tried. That's what leaves the empty space while and after the view has shrunk.

Comment: Then you need to animate those Views with the Animation of the View you're trying to get rid of.

Comment: But I don't know exactly where all the other views will end up. And if i try to put fixed distances and sizes, it won't work on different screen shapes and sizes.

Comment: If you're targeting Android 3.0+, I would try out the `ObjectAnimator` or `ValueAnimator` class that can actually dynamically animate the attributes or values of the `View`. In your case, you probably want to animate the `LayoutParams` height and width.

Comment: Thanks @Brian that kinda worked even though it took me almost all night to figure out how it all works..